# Tools related question on SO

Tags: discussion

My question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17753612/java-code-scrubber at SO was closed and down voted.

While I understand mods are trying their best to keep questions on track as given in the reasoning and have great respect for the work they do, I am trying to figure out a way of getting answers from experienced SO community without raising spam war or ire of moderators.

I have a real problem related to code as described in the question. I would assume many people do face similar problems and would like to see their code cleaned. My question is about looking for solutions to my problem - how to clean up java code.

What will be the best way to describe this kind of problem? Or is this completely out side of scope of SO? As I normally do, I tried searching for answers before submitting question and could not find anything satisfactory.

Comment: You'd be better off doing a search and choosing a tool which cleans up your unused code (if any exist), then asking specific questions about using that tool if you encounter problems. There's not a way to make a question asking for a list of tools on topic.

Comment: _mods are trying their best_ -- your question was put on hold (not closed) by regular users, not by moderator. Look up their names in the notice written in large font: "put on hold as off-topic by..."

Answer (score 5):

If you have a specific question about using a specific programming tool, your question is on-topic on Stack Overflow.  If you're just looking for recommendations for tools, your question is off-topic.  Just ask how to solve the problem that you're facing instead of asking for a tool or product recommendation.

Comment: Might the question not be, and I hesitate to say this because I don't know for sure, more appropriate for programmers? It seems to be about code-refactoring once you remove the shopping part and it's in the same ball-park as the famous: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/155488/ive-inherited-200k-lines-of-spaghetti-code-what-now and

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Either that or a long series of questions on Code Review.

Comment: Thank all for the help. I have rephrased the question. However still  trying to understand so that I can avoid these mistakes in future. Basically it looks like if I say how can I can clean up my java code is ok, If I specifically ask how to clean up the code using eclipse, its ok, but as my google searches did not reveal any tool, asking if such beast exists is not ok as that can end up in flame war.